# One PWM timer to two outputs?

Tags: atmega, pwm

first post here, so sorry for any bad styling.

I'm working on a group project and using an Atmega328, without going into specifics, I need to drive two fans, two servos, and 1 CTC based function from 3 timers. To my question then; there's registers OCRx A and B that I'm using to drive the fans at variable speeds, and using a similar method for the servos. Setting up a very basic PWM script, I've noticed that both registers will drive a fan, however when I attempt to use either register independently (fan 1 on, 2 off, then change), OCRxB will not produce an output.

Here's a cut-out of my setup code:

```
void setup_timers () {
// Set Timer0 to Fast PWM mode
TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01) | (1 << WGM00);

// Set Timer0 to clear OCR0 A/B on match
TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A1) | (1 << COM0A0) | (1 << COM0B1) | (1 << COM0B0);
TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01);
TCNT0 = 0;

// Set OCR0 A/B
DDRD = 0xFF;}
```

Now, ideally, this will set up both registers in Timer 0 for outputs. I'm sending this signal to a transistor, which then powers the fans as determined by this next bit:

```
int main () {
setup_timers();

while (1) {

    /* Timer 0; OCR0A (i = 0, L), OCR0B (i = 1, R), i = 2 denotes both fans */

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        // Cycle Fans Left/Right/Both

        for (uint8_t j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            // Cycle Speed 

            if (i == 2) {
                // Check motor; run timer 0 A/B as required
                OCR0A = 0xFF * j / 4;
                OCR0B = 0xFF * j / 4;
                _delay_ms(2000);
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                OCR0A = 0xFF * j / 4;
                OCR0B = 0;
                _delay_ms(2000);
            }
            else if (i == 0) {
                OCR0A = 0;
                OCR0B = 0xFF * j / 4;
                _delay_ms(2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
return 1; }
```

Now I know this could be done better, this segment has a heap of other tests cut out. The main issue here is that Fan 1 will run (directed by OCR0A), but Fan 2 is completely ignored. I have read through the data sheet a few times, but it was a bit unclear as to whether this is actually possible, it did say something about OCRxB not being stored, and I have seen other posts asking after that. From what I understand they are independent registers, but is it possible that OCRxA is retained, but after writing OCRxB it is impossible to execute?

Or maybe I'm completely wrong, certainly wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: your output pins may not actually share the same timer. check the timer output mapping to the physical pins you are using.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure fan is connected to *(PCINT21/OC0B/T1) PD5* pin ? BTW: I think outer loop should go to *<3* only and *0xFF * j / 4* probably does not provide *0xFF* for *j=4* but *252*.

Comment: @TMa - You may want to rethink your comment about "j". If j=4 and noting that 0xFF=255 it follows that (255*4)/4 == 255, not 252.

Comment: I think it's compiled as *255/4 * j=63.75-->63 * j*. And in runtime evaluated only *63 * j*, i.e. *63 * 4 = 252*. At least depends on compiler optimization. But it's not important issue in test. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KyranF, I'm aware that there are two output pins, I've been able to get each to work solely from OCR0A, but not have OCR0B (D6) acting independent of OCR0A (D5).

Comment: @Oman they can use different timers too!

Comment: @KyranF, what do you mean? I have 3 timers, and I'm using them all, but need to put things on one timer.

Comment: do yo know if both PWM peripherals can use Timer 0?

Comment: @KyranF that's the issue. I can run PWM through either port by not setting OCR0B, but when I try to set OCR0B and all the com register etc. there's nothing from the output pin. As a worst case scenario, do you guys know if I can run a servo with digital, not PWM?

Comment: Yes, of course. I would never run a servo off PWM, it's entirely unsuited. If you are not already using Arduino for your Atmega328 project, then you can at least see how they do it and reverse engineer the C code. http://arduino.cc/en/reference/servo They use timers and ISRs (I think, otherwise simple timekeeping and using elapsed time to make the output changes) to service the digital output pin appropriately. This is far better than PWM, which with 8-bit resolution and being stuck between 1-2ms time frame, it's very hard to get low speed PWM, at 500Hz you only have 10 positions for 8bit PWM

Comment: (continued from the 10 positions thing) Because you are going from  1/50th of a second to 2/50th of a second is your servo command window, and 500Hz PWM gives you 0-255 steps in 1/500th of a second. So 10/500th and 20/500th, you will have very granular position control. Of course you can crank up the PWM frequency but yeah.. just do with with simple timers and digital IO, in microcontroller land doing something every 20ms is not hard

Comment: Hm, timers is a reasonably good idea, how might I run two CTC's from 1 timer? At the moment, my time window is very small, so something simple would be great. Thanks for all the help man.

Comment: Oh, and I'm using Atmel Studio, running an Atmega328 on it's own, attaching it to a custom circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there was some issue with predetermined values, by setting COM1A0 and COM1B0, Timer 1 can be configured to give independent signals. This is the setup code that works:

```
void setup_timers () {

TCCR1A |= (1 << WGM11) | (1 << WGM10);
TCCR1A |= (1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1A0) | (1 << COM1B1) | (1 << COM1B0);
TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11);
TCNT1 = 0;

DDRB = 0xFF;}
```

I'm still having trouble getting it to properly control the motors, but the servos work well, and it can be done.

Note: Timer 1 actually has two separate outputs, but Timer 0/2 do not. To get dual outputs, you need to toggle WGMx2 and the COMxB 0/1 registers, when WGMx2 is set, OCRxA will not output properly, but OCRxB will, with some fiddling. When WGMx2 is not set, it disable OCRxB, and OCRxA will work as normal, to get independent outputs, you will need to take this into account.